# Consuming OTRS TicketConnector from .NET apps

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, otrs

I want to consume **[OTRS TicketConnector](http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/3.3/en/html/genericinterface.html#generic-ticket-connector)** webservice in a .NET app.

Normally, the easiest way to get connected to a webservice is to import its WSDL via 'Add Service Reference'. Unfortunately, OTRS TicketConnector doesn't publish the WSDL.

I've found a custom WSDL for TicketConnector [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbeijen/otrs/master/development/webservices/GenericTicketConnector.wsdl). But when I'm trying to use it in 'Add Service Reference' it leads to an empty Reference.cs showing the following errors:

```
Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: There was a problem loading the XSD documents provided: a reference to a schema type with name 'OTRS_TicketCreate' and namespace 'http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/' could not be resolved because the type definition could not be found in the schema for targetNamespace 'http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/'. Please check the XSD documents provided and try again.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/']/wsdl:portType[@name='GenericTicketConnector_Interface']

Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/']/wsdl:portType[@name='GenericTicketConnector_Interface']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/']/wsdl:binding[@name='GenericTicketConnector_Service']

Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/']/wsdl:binding[@name='GenericTicketConnector_Service']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/']/wsdl:service[@name='GenericTicketConnector']/wsdl:port[@name='GenericTicketConnector_endPoint']

Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.
```

I've tried to import the WSDL above via svcutil with no success.
Also, I've tried to import this WSDL via 'Add Web Reference' with the same results.

So my question is: **how do you consume OTRS TicketConnector service from a .NET app?**
Maybe you can give a code snippet or a proper WSDL that can be successfully imported with the .NET tools?
Also, I would appreciate any help in resolving issues with the WSDL errors I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [OTRS community forum](http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=25984&p=103824#p103824), I've got the answer. **WSDLs** for **Ticket Connector** are available at [GitHub](https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/tree/master/development/webservices).

Comment: 404 not found. do you know where are the wsdls for import now?

Comment: @artgrohe: Sorry, it was 4yrs ago. You might have a better chance of getting an answer in the forum topic I referenced in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I found them:) They are now YAML files in the official documentation at http://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/genericinterface.html#genericinterface-bundled-connectors-examples
I mean thats not exactly what I was looking for, but it does help me